# Error type "enum_orders_carriercompany" does not exist

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js, enum

Estoy trabajando con Nodejs, Sequelize y PostgreSql, y necesito agregar valores a un enum_orders_carrierCompany. Intente correr el script tanto desde DBavear como desde una migration en sequelize y en ambos casos me devuelve el mismo error.

**Desde DBavear:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Usando migration en Sequelize:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un dato; instalé "pgAdmin 4" y ahí pude correr el script `ALTER ENUM enum_orders_carrierCompany ADD VALUE 'LA'`, pero me gustaría poder correrlo con una migration de Sequelize para replicar en otros ambientes al hacer los respectivos deployments.

Agrego las versiones que estoy usando:

- Nodejs: v14.8
- Sequelize: v5.22
- PostgreSql: v12
- DBeaver: v21.2.5

Les agradecería un ayuda por favor.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola! ¿Versión de PostgreSQL? ¿Versión de DBeaver? Es curioso porque en la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertype.html) eso no va como dices... por favor, ve a [edit] y amplía tu pregunta con la info faltante.

Comment: Si, disculpa q no lo agregue antes. Recien las dependencias con sus versiones, igual te los comparto tmb por aqui:
 - Nodejs: v14.8
 - Sequelize: v5.22
 - PostgreSql: v12
 - DBeaver: v21.2.5

Comment: Otra cosa, el servidor donde tengo la base datos postgreSql corre en un container de docker, no se si eso podra afectar en algo.

Comment: Es un error de postgresql, ese amigo corre igual dentro o fuera de un contenedor ;) Revisa la respuesta sugerida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues tu consulta está mal hecha y/o pgAdmin está soportando algún legacy que no está [documentado](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertype.html) en ninguna parte de PostgreSQL para la versión que mencionas.

Si uno crea un enum usando

```
CREATE TYPE pepito_enum_type AS ENUM ('mail', 'text_sms', 'Phone_no');
```

La forma de modificarlo es

```
ALTER TYPE pepito_enum_type ADD VALUE 'LA';
```

Y vas a ver la modificación en los detalles del enum.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, el problema estaba en la consulta o la notación que usa para llamar al type. lo escribi de la siguiente manera y me lo tomo, pero calculo que dependera de como este definido el esquema.

Desde DBeaver
ALTER TYPE public."enum_orders_carrierCompany" ADD VALUE 'LA'

En sequelize migration
up: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      "ALTER TYPE public.\"enum_orders_carrierCompany\" ADD VALUE 'PA';"
    );
  },

Muchas gracias amigo!!

Saludos!!